# How do I declare a read-only array tuple in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

We can declare a typed tuple in TypeScript, for example, with the type annotation `[string, number]`. This means an array of 2 elements where the first element needs to be a string and the second a number.

We can also declare read-only arrays with `ReadonlyArray<string>` which means a read-only array of strings.

Now I want to have a read-only tuple like in the first example, but I want it to be read-only like in the second example. How would I declare that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Typescript version 3.4 you can just prefix tuple type with `readonly` keyword ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4#improvements-for-readonlyarray-and-readonly-tuples)).

> TypeScript 3.4 also introduces new support for `readonly` tuples. We can prefix any tuple type with the `readonly` keyword to make it a `readonly` tuple, much like we now can with array shorthand syntax. As you might expect, unlike ordinary tuples whose slots could be written to, `readonly` tuples only permit reading from those positions.
>
> ```
> function foo(pair: readonly [string, string]) {
>     console.log(pair[0]);   // okay
>     pair[1] = "hello!";     // error
> }
> ```

Answer (score 24):

### Solution for TypeScript 3.4+: Const Assertion

With **const assertions**, the compiler can be told to treat an array or an object as immutable, meaning that their properties are read-only. This also allows the creation of literal tuple types with narrower type inference (i.e. your  `["a", "b"]` can be of type `["a", "b"]`, rather than `string[]` without specifiying the whole thing as a contextual type)

The syntax:

```typescript
const foo = ["text", 1] as const // or
const foo = <const> ["text", 1]
// typeof foo:
readonly ["text", 1]
```

It can also be used for object literals:

```typescript
const myObj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: ["a", "b"],
  baz: true,
} as const
// typeof myObj:
{ readonly foo: 1, readonly bar: readonly ["a", "b"], readonly baz: true }
```

[Here is the extended information](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510) of the corresponding PR.

Answer (score 23):

Since the type `[string, number]` already is an `Array`, you can simply use:

`Readonly<[string, number]>`

Example:

```
let tuple: Readonly<[string, number]> = ['text', 3, 4, 'another text'];

tuple[0] = 'new text'; //Error (Readonly)

let string1: string = tuple[0]; //OK!
let string2: string = tuple[1]; //Error (Type number)
let number1: number = tuple[0]; //Error (Type string)
let number2: number = tuple[1]; //OK!
let number3: number = tuple[2]; //Error (Type any)
```

Comment: I think this will give you a read-only array of writable tuples. What I want is a single read-only tuple. Try to compile this and you will see `const x: ReadonlyArray<[string, number]> = ["a", 1];`

Comment: It's writable after you transpile to JavaScript, yes. But you will get TypeScript error when you try to do `tuple[0] = 'new text';`.

Comment: I misread `Readonly` in your answer as `ReadonlyArray`. In deed `Readonly<T>` works :-).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get no type error when I try to modify the Readonly array. This is the code I'm trying and TypeScript doesn't complain: `const a: Readonly<number[]> = [1,2,3]; a[1] = 4`. No error in my app! I'm on TS `3.3.0-dev.20181208`. Also doesn't work in the playground (at time of writing)! See: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20a%3A%20Readonly%3Cnumber%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%0Aa%5B1%5D%20%3D%204%0A

Comment: Confirmed, `Readonly<Array<T>>` doesn't work, but `ReadonlyArray<Array<T>>` does: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28968

Comment: @trusktr The `Readonly` and `ReadonlyArray` types are not interchangeable like that.

Comment: Ah, interesting. It would be intuitive if they were. After all, array indexes are just object keys (from high-level perspective).

Comment: the first line produces a typescript error: `Type '[string, number, number, string]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [string, number]'. Source has 4 element(s) but target allows only 2.(2322)`

Comment: Seems `readonly [string, number]` is the simplest form.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer leaves array mutation methods unaffected, which can cause unsoundness in the following way:

```
const tuple: Readonly<[number, string]> = [0, ''];
tuple.shift();
let a = tuple[0]; // a: number, but at runtime it will be a string
```

The code below fixes this issue, and includes Sergey Shandar's destructuring fix. You'll need to use `--noImplicitAny` for it to work properly.

```
type ArrayItems<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer TItems> ? TItems : never;

type ExcludeProperties<TObj, TKeys extends string | number | Symbol> = Pick<TObj, Exclude<keyof TObj, TKeys>>;

type ArrayMutationKeys = Exclude<keyof any[], keyof ReadonlyArray<any>> | number;

type ReadonlyTuple<T extends any[]> = Readonly<ExcludeProperties<T, ArrayMutationKeys>> & {
    readonly [Symbol.iterator]: () => IterableIterator<ArrayItems<T>>;
};

const tuple: ReadonlyTuple<[number, string]> = [0, ''];
let a = tuple[0]; // a: number
let b = tuple[1]; // b: string
let c = tuple[2]; // Error when using --noImplicitAny
tuple[0] = 1; // Error
let [d, e] = tuple; // d: number, e: string
let [f, g, h] = tuple; // Error
```

Comment: In recent versions of typescript, with `Readonly<[number, string]>` is same as `readonly [number, string]`. And this case, the method `shift` does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

`Readonly<[string, T]>` doesn't allow destruction. For example

```
const tuple: Readonly<[string, number]> = ["text", 4]

const [n, v] = tuple // error TS2488: Type 'Readonly<[string, number]>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

So, it's better to use a custom interface

```
export interface Entry<T> {
    readonly [0]: string
    readonly [1]: T
    readonly [Symbol.iterator]: () => IterableIterator<string|T>
}
```

For example

```
const tuple: Entry<number> = ["text", 4]

const [name, value] = tuple // ok
const nameCheck: string = name
const valueCheck: number = value
```

Answer (score 2):

As of v3.2.2, there's no perfect way of making a readonly tuple type without converting it to an object that *looks* like an array, but is not.

The lead architect of TypeScript has said [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26864#issuecomment-418382690) on the topic of combining `Readonly<T>` with tuple types.

Here is the best solution I've come up with:

```
type ReadonlyTuple<T extends any[]> = {
    readonly [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof []>]: T[P]
} & Iterable<T[number]>
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript Version 5.4.2

if you have an object with `as const` appended, it will create a readonly object.

use this object to derive a strongly typed tuple from

This should help, [check out the playground link as well](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgazgewO5wPICMBWUC8UAShAMbIBOAJgDwDOwFAlnAOZQA%20UcArgLZYIFTlDogByADYAaKD0Qp0APgDcAKDXk4DKKQCGwCK0pMIdAlADeaqFABEABjsAuewEE4IO9Jv2AnC72AOIQcEJ6kt6%20dgCMTq52AKJwhhTAeix8ocB2agC%20UHrmWgzqmsjawFAQAB56fGCS0ITWtmEMEFSu%20obGzGY%20tljIUq4AQiNNenAAFA4AlAT4hABmEXTQAPxQjDzQrmuSG4NQfCBuFBSuANp2fEw1nd47FHuyMQBMAMyyt3qXdgAuoD8oVihVShoSlVgMgSHoqBVJCAACo8RrNKA0aFQFHVGqGOBUczwJBoTC4JQzMAUZBgOiuFHzfBKKy%20CgQYA8ChwKDYHBkYAAOmy-To1Np9PmQr4ejAMxm1wQEBAsgAbhFAczWa1bFAOVyeVAlSqwVBlSBkCtceqImaUSbLdaUcCzdDfHlFnQDEw6CtTOYZhyEUiQMaLVabbjHZGXVrriC8lCITC4RAERg4MiLhQMCsANIqugYCgao4WGi%20HF42qE4mwBTk-knHEANXxdfMdgtdDsIjsZd7aipvhpdIZNt86QorE5rlbakWLLZtgN3N5-MFIpSYol4-mvlsMrlCsdtskWoIOsPerXRsdZojzvP9pjztdRV0KdEPr9Af16aIlmYbXDeermiqsYnOBtgOk%20uIgjBUCAuo4Gejex7yoqFrnpeLJgTs-yzlUyyEN2RZ9tsipCjRjofuClTzNcDiAlAribqQworByEAAF4QDMZYHuBiyfjs4AQJG07ER2oT1uRIC9lA2zBkByJQDM8FMgmbHEIBoY0HBkHvkoCbqHkZQlFIEBCpIyCsDMsLwmpqLok0My1PUGLzPM6hWU0tn2Y5aYZsBOZ5oWikloOHl1A0TSyApvY%20X5ELWYFDlOYBmbZpcEVFtF6yxV5CX2IOdg%20WoQA)

```
type UnknownObj = Record<string | number | symbol, unknown>;

const categories = {
  "0": "Any",
  "9": "General",
  "10": "Entertainment"
} as const;

const example = {
  nested: categories,
  bool: Boolean(0) === false ? true : false,
  myArr: ["mixed", true, 123, ["arr"]]
} as const;

const toReadonlyTuple = <const T extends UnknownObj>(props: T)=> {
  return Object.entries(props).map(([key, val])=> {
    return [key as keyof T, val as T[keyof T]] as const
  }) satisfies (readonly [keyof T, T[keyof T]])[]
}

const toReadOnlyArrOfKeysOrvals = <
  const T extends UnknownObj,
  const V extends "keys" | "vals"
>(
  props: T,
  target: V
) => {
  return Object.entries(props)
    .map(([key, val]) => {
      return [key as keyof T, val as T[keyof T]] as const satisfies readonly [
        keyof T,
        T[keyof T]
      ];
    })
    .map(([key, val]) =>
      target === "keys" ? ([...[key]] as const)[0] : Object.freeze(val)
    ) as  typeof target extends "keys" ? readonly (keyof T)[] : Readonly<T[keyof T]>[];
};

console.log(toReadonlyTuple(example));
console.log(toReadOnlyArrOfKeysOrvals(example, "keys"));
console.log(toReadOnlyArrOfKeysOrvals(example, "vals"))
```

The generated declaration definitions for either function

```
declare const toReadonlyTuple: <const T extends UnknownObj>(props: T) => (readonly [keyof T, T[keyof T]])[];

declare const toReadOnlyArrOfKeysOrvals: <const T extends UnknownObj, const V extends "keys" | "vals">(props: T, target: V) => V extends "keys" ? readonly (keyof T)[] : Readonly<T[keyof T]>[];
```

console output:

```bash
[LOG]: [["nested", {
  "0": "Any",
  "9": "General",
  "10": "Entertainment"
}], ["bool", true], ["myArr", ["mixed", true, 123, ["arr"]]]] 
[LOG]: ["nested", "bool", "myArr"] 
[LOG]: [{
  "0": "Any",
  "9": "General",
  "10": "Entertainment"
}, true, ["mixed", true, 123, ["arr"]]]
```

Comment: Why the extra indirection? This seems like an odd way to answer the question....

Answer (score -1):

You can invoke `Object.freeze` while creating an array to make it readonly.

```js
const arr = Object.freeze(["text", 2, 3]);
```

This will automatically convert the type to `readonly (string | number)[]` in TypeScript, and will be readonly during runtime as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about how to create a readonly *Tuple*, not a readonly hetergeneous array.