# Why can't I make an Array readonly this way in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, readonly, readonly-collection

The documentation shows (#ReadOnlyArray) how to do it using an interface, but as I am exploring the language I wondered why does this not work as well ?

```
type TraverseTuple<T extends Array<unknown>> = {
     readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
}

const test: TraverseTuple<[string, number, string, number]> = ['s', 1, 'o', 2];

test[1] = 0; // not readonly !
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is specifically not supported. The ability to map tuples was just recently introduces to typescript 3.1 with [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063). From the PR:

> A `readonly`, `-readonly`, or `+readonly` annotation in a homomorphic mapped type currently has no effect on array or tuple elements (we might consider mapping from `Array` to `ReadonlyArray` and vice versa, although that technically isn't structure preserving because it adds or removes methods).

Comment: Does it mean there was a breaking change in TS ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42696355/3570903
Should I open an issue for this ?

Comment: @pirix-gh don't know, I would have to research what the previous behavior was

Answer (score 4):

There is a built-in read-only array type, which makes arrays read only (unless asserted back to a plain array).

```
const test: ReadonlyArray<string|number> = ['s', 1, 'o', 2];

test[1] = 0;
```

But, for tuples you need to create an explicit type, like this:

```
const test: Readonly<{ 0: string, 1: number, 2: string, 3: number }> = ['s', 1, 'o', 2];

test[1] = 1;
```