# How to specify array length for ReadonlyArray<number>?

Tags: typescript

I'm making a functional-style chess game engine just as a fun intro to typescript. I have this type:

```
type GridCoordinates = [number, number];
```

...and I've defined 64 number pairs as arrays to be able to refer to board positions by algebraic notation everywhere, which I freeze so I don't have to worry about accidentally mutating them:

```
export const A1 = Object.freeze([0,0]);
```

Unfortunately, freezing the object causes typescript to see this as not satisfying the GridCoordinates type -- it sees a `ReadonlyArray<number>` and throws an error.

I could specify the GridCoordinates type as `ReadonlyArray<number>`, which accepts the frozen array, but then I lose the ability to specify the array length (must be 2).

Is there any way to specify array length as part of a type definition that accepts frozen arrays?

Comment: How about `type GridCoordinates = [number, number] & ReadonlyArray<number>`?

Comment: Hm. No, doesn't work. That produces `Type 'ReadonlyArray<any>' is not assignable to type 'GridCoordinates'.
  Type 'ReadonlyArray<any>' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1, pop, push, and 9 more.ts(2322)`

Comment: oh, that's unfortunate. I don't know how TypeScript internally implements the type `ReadonlyArray` but you might have to inspect that to see how to answer this question.

Comment: Wait, I found the answer. It should be `Readonly<[number, number]>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42696098/1541563

Comment: Eh, there is [currently no support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26864) for readonly tuples.  You might be able to get some of the behavior you want with a custom type like `{readonly 0: number, readonly 1: number}` but it won't be seen as both a tuple and a readonly data structure.

Comment: The error you mention is only indicative of the fact that `Object.freeze()` acting on a tuple returns `ReadonlyArray`.  You can either [merge another overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) into `Object.freeze()` or just manually [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that the return value is the type you want.